# Blackberry Version checking

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Hi i need a code for comparing blackberry software version. if blackberry device software version is higher than OS 6 then continue the app otherwise prompt user dialog showing upgrade OS first and exit the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a better approach than you described.

Use preprocessor and [alx-task](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#alx) to build different application versions for different OS version.

Then you will have one alx + set of folders with cod files, where every folder has cod files for particular platform version. Alx file will contain directives to install cod files from the suitable folder, according to the connected device OS version.

Comment: no this is not required.. i want app to check the blackberry version than compare with a list of bb os version if current version is greater than bb OS 6 than continue otherwise exit app..

Comment: note that an application made with old SDK would not appear good on newer RIM OS versions. Yes it will run, but it will not appear good.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
String deviceOS = DeviceInfo.getPlatformVersion();
```

Comment: please provide a complete solution as to compare this version with other blackberry version list.